# how to make my css style apply on my pages

Tags: html, css, django

I've been using django for a while but I'm just a beginner in css, I don't know much. I put style on my style.css file which is in the static folder and I placed the link in my template base.html but when I launch the server, the css style does not apply. what to do?

mon templates base.html

```
{% load static %}
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Lax blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <h1>Lax Blog</h1>
      {% if user.is_authenticated %} {% if user.profile_photo %}
      <img class="avatar" src="{{ user.profile_photo.url }}" />
      {% else %}
      <img class="avatar" src="{% static 'images/default_profile.png'%}" />
      {% endif %}
      <p><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Accueil</a></p>

      <p>
        Vous etes connecté entant que {{request.user }}
        <a href="{% url 'deconnexion' %}">Se déconnecter</a>
      </p>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="main">{% block content %}{% endblock content %}</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

mon fichier style.css

```
body {
    background-color: white;
    color: blue;
}

html {
    font-family:'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
    height: 100%; /* Full-height: remove this if you want "auto" height */
    width: 220px; /* Set the width of the sidebar */
    position: fixed; /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll) */
    z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
    top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
    left: 0;
    background-color: #1d3030;
    color:  #ffffe6;
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

/* le lien de navigation */
.sidebar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:yellow;
    display: block;
}

.main {
    margin-left: 240px; /* Same as the width of the sidebar */
    padding: 20px;
}

.avatar {
    width: 80%;
    border-radius: 10%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

I thought the problem was on the browser, but I tried with firefox, edge and chrome but nothing worked. I delete the caches, always the same thing

Comment: if you look at the network tab of the browser dev tools, does it load the stylesheet?

Comment: Also you can check source code of the page using `ctrl+U` then click on css file and see whether it is opening or not (or shows 404 page).

Comment: You can try running ./manage.py collectstatic

Comment: thanks , i added this line below in settings.py and it work                                                                         
                                                                                                                 
     STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR.joinpath('static/')]